# Determine all $z \in\Bbb C$ such that $z^8 + 3iz^4 + 4 = 0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Trying to study for my final, and this question came up.

Any hints as how to how to begin would be greatly appreciated.

-edit-

thank you all for your help. I would have never thought of that in a million years. I'm going to post the answer just so anybody searching this can find it.

let $w = z^4$

Now we have: $w^2 +3iw + 4 = 0$

Which becomes: $(w-i)(w+4i)$

Which gives us $w-i = 0$ and $w+4i = 0$

So $w=i$ or $w=-4i$ 

Since $w = z^4$ we take $\sqrt[4]{w} = z$

So we have to calculate the four roots of each factor found

Start with $w = i$ which in polar form is $1(cos(90)+isin(90))$

The complex root theorem is:
$\sqrt[n]{r}(cos(\cfrac{ \theta + 2k\pi}{n}) + isin(\cfrac{ \theta + 2k\pi}{n}))$ for $k = 0,1,2,...,n-1$

Using that theorem, we can get the correct roots.

Comment: Try substituting $w=z^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice question. Notice that if we relabel $z^4$ as $w$ then we have:

$$z^8 +3iz^4+4 \equiv  w^2+3iw + 4$$

We can use the quadratic formula to solve $w^2+3iw+4=0$, where $a=1$, $b=3i$ and $c=4$.

\begin{array}{ccc}
w &=& \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
&=& \frac{-3i\pm\sqrt{-9-16}}{2} \\
&=& \frac{-3i \pm 5i}{2} \\
&=& -4i \ \text{ or } \ i
\end{array}

Since $w^2+3iw+4=0 \iff w \in \{-4i,i\}$ and $w = z^4$, you're left needing to solve $z^4=i$ and $z^4=-4i$. First, consider the case $z^4=i$. We know that $i = \operatorname{e}^{i(\pi/2+2\pi n)}$ hence:

\begin{array}
 zz &=& i^{1/4} \\
&=& \operatorname{e}^{i(\pi/8+\pi n/2)} \\
&=& \operatorname{e}^{5i/8}, \ \ \operatorname{e}^{9i/8}, \ \ \operatorname{e}^{13i/8}, \ \ \operatorname{e}^{9i/4}.
\end{array}

Now do the same to solve $z^4 = - 4i$.

Comment: @WendellBlatt You're very welcome; I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: it's a quadratic in $z^4$.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $w = z^4$. You get $w^2 + 3i w + 4 = 0$, which is just a quadratic equation you can solve.